# UIView frame be changed to 0,0,0,0 when another UIView be resized in Xcode 6.1 Interface Build

Tags: uiview, interface-builder, xcode6.1

the problem is shown in the Video

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16843197/Xcode%20Interface%20Builder%20-%20problem.mov

how can I solve it?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I try to

1. remove Xcode 6.1
2. delete folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
3. delete folder ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
4. install Xcode 6.0.1

and I solved the problem.

Is it a bug in Xcode 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

I found the second solution:

Disable "AutoLayout" in Interface Builder